# How to rebase cloned branch with master

Tags: git, github, rebase

I am working with another developer on the same branch. He first created branch `abc` and then I cloned it:

```
git clone -b abc https://github.cerner.com/path/to/some/repo
```

This just created a branch `abc` and no `master` branch.

We pushed our changes and now I want to rebase it with `master`.

Since there is no local `master` branch I am wondering how do I rebase `abc` with `master`?

Answer (score 1):

> Your branch and 'origin/abc have diverged, and have 13 and 4 different commits each

Putting the non-existing `master` aside, you should do a `git pull --rebase` first, that would rebase your local `abc` commits on top of `origin/abc`.
Then you can push.

Regarding `master`, do a `git fetch` followed by a `git branch -avv`.
If you see an `origin/master`, you can create a local `master` branch:

```
git branch master origin/master
```

If you don't see any `origin/master` (no `master` was ever created), then you can simply create and push one from your current branch:

```
git checkout -b master
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score -1):

Cloning just a branch, except in very special cases, is not the thing to do.

If you pushed all your commits, just clone again but this time normally:

```
git clone https://github.cerner.com/path/to/some/repo
```

Then rebase...

Comment: Why?! Why not just fetch `master` into the existing clone?!

Comment: that created a new clone inside. When i did git status i get `On branch abc
Your branch and 'origin/abc have diverged,
and have 13 and 4 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)`